# jQuery Ajax Call not calling success

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

I'm facing a problem with an ajax request. whenever I run the following I am getting an `x` (as what is being generated from the error function in the request below) but I should be getting the tick image since I confirmed that the call did actually make the change in the system.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/URL",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { action: 'assoc_users', username: 'testuser', name: 'testname' },
    success: function(){
    $("#user_1_image").attr("src","http://domain.com/check.png");
  },
    error: function(){
    $("#user1_status").html("x");
  }
});
```

Data that will be the output:

```
{status: 'OK', payload: ''}
```

Comment: Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: I'm not using a console or anything. Basically a PHP page returning a value

Comment: I think what @ExplosionPills means is are you getting any javascript errors in Firefox?

Comment: No, Explosion Pills asked if you are using the console of you browser (Firebug in Firefox as example) to track if JavaScript is reporting a problem.

Comment: success: function(){ whats coming from the url? u haven't used anything coming back from the url

Comment: does the action or URL returns json format data ?

Comment: The URL returns JSON. if it's an error then status: 'ERROR' would occur

Comment: okay you can go with  the second one in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Parse error in your json string, check your json string first

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    action: 'assoc_users
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

I've corrected your json string and tried it out. Try this it works,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var actions = { "action": "assoc_users", "username": "testuser", "name": "testname" };
    $.ajax({
    url: "/URL",
    type: "POST",
    data: actions,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        alert('action'+data.action+'username'+data.username+'name'+data.name); // this is to check whats coming from the server side
        $("#user_1_image").attr("src","http://domain.com/check.png");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception){
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
  }
}); 
});
```

in the php file

```
<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting valid json from your specified url then this will work because in your code you are not passing data in the success function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/URL",
    type: "POST",
    dataType:'json',
    data: { action: 'assoc_users', username: 'testuser', name: 'testname' },
    success: function(data){
      if(data){
        $("#user_1_image").attr("src","http://domain.com/check.png");
      }
    },
    error: function(){
       $("#user1_status").html("x");
    }
});
```

Comment: I received the same problem removing the dataType

Comment: try the second one if you are getting json from that url then you have to pass it throgh success function and if there is data then give the attr to the img.

Answer (score 0):

kindly use it  , MAy be quotes are creating problem , so try it .

```
$.ajax({
url: '/URL',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: { action: 'assoc_users', username: 'testuser', name: 'testname' },
success: function(){
$('#user_1_image').attr('src','http://domain.com/check.png');
},
error: function(){
$('#user1_status').html('x');
}
});
```